# not(:checked) not working if checkbox nested into element

Tags: html, css, checked

I have the following code to hide or show the element `id="my_text"` depending on if the checkbox is checked not:

```
<style>
input[id=my_checkbox]:not(:checked) ~ #my_text  {
    display:none;
}
</style>

<div class="trigger">
    <input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox">
</div>

<div id="my_text">
    Hide/show this sentence.
</div>
```

This isn't working, the element `id="my_text"` is always shown.

But when I remove the `<div>` the checkbox is nested in (or at least the closing `</div>` tag) like this:

```
<style>
input[id=my_checkbox]:not(:checked) ~ #my_text  {
    display:none;
}
</style>

<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox">

<div id="my_text">
    Hide/show this sentence.
</div>
```

it's working as expected.

Why isn't my CSS working if the checkbox is nested in an element?

Comment: In css with `~` you are selecting a sibling element. But in your markup `#my_text` is not a sibling of the `input` but of the `div`, I'm afraid with your current markup it is not possible to achieve what you are trying to do with just CSS afaik because we don't have a parent selector

Comment: @empiric Spot on. Thumbs up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)

> The general sibling combinator (~) separates two selectors and matches
> the second element only if it follows the first element (though not
> necessarily immediately), and both are children of the same parent
> element.

You need to use the [HTML `<label>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label) which represents a caption for an item in a user interface to make it work, since css doesn't have the  [parent selector](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/) yet

```css
input[id=my_checkbox]:not(:checked) ~ #my_text  {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="trigger">
    <label for=my_checkbox>checkbox</label>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" id="my_checkbox">
<div id="my_text">
    Hide/show this sentence.
</div>
```